# UE4 AddDynamic macro doesn't work on 4.26

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am stuck with this error:

> C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Unreal
> Projects\ClassicArcade\Source\ClassicArcade\Floor.cpp(22) : error
> C2664: "void
> TSparseDynamicDelegate<FComponentBeginOverlapSignature_MCSignature,UPrimitiveComponent,FComponentBeginOverlapSignatureInfoGetter>::__Internal_AddDynamic(UserClass
> *,void (__cdecl AFloor::* )(UPrimitiveComponent *,AActor *,UPrimitiveComponent *,int32,bool,const FHitResult &),FName)": nie mo?na dokona? konwersji argumentu 2 z "void (__cdecl AFloor::*
> )(AActor *,UPrimitiveComponent *,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)" do
> "void (__cdecl AFloor::* )(UPrimitiveComponent *,AActor
> *,UPrimitiveComponent *,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)"
> with
> [
> UserClass=AFloor
> ]

"nie mo?na dokona? konwersji argumentu 2 z" means "that cannot converse second parameter from .... to ...."

[image: Error screen]

Code:

```
    BoxCollision = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("BoxCollision"));
    BoxCollision->SetupAttachment(SceneRoot);

    BoxCollision->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AFloor::OnOverlap);


void AFloor::OnOverlap(class AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (OtherActor && (OtherActor != this))
    {
        GameMode->SpawnNextFloor(OtherActor->GetActorLocation());
    }
}
```

In header file I have `UFUNCTION()` specifier. Visual Studio gives me message that there is no function template compatible with parameters.

Comment: The signatures don't match according to the error. I guess AFloor::OnOverlap's arguments should be `(UPrimitiveComponent*, AActor*, UPrimitiveComponent*, int32, bool, const FHitResult&)`? Also note that the signature needs to match in both AFloor::OnOverlap`s declaration (.h) and definition (.cpp).

Comment: I take this function definition from UE4 documentation so it should be good

Comment: It'll either be from a version older or newer than the one you're using. I think the version used in documentation is stated at the top of the webpage, the vast majority are old.

Comment: Ok, i've tried your hint and it works, thank U :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header:

```
UFUNCTION()
        void OnOverlap(class UPrimitiveComponent* Comp, class AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult);
```

Implementation:

```
void AFloor::OnOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent*, class AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent*, int32, bool, const FHitResult&)
{
    if (OtherActor && (OtherActor != this))
    {
        GameMode->SpawnNextFloor(OtherActor->GetActorLocation());
    }
}
```